# how to use linq on a list<T> to generate a list<lists<T>> in C#

Tags: c#, linq, generics, list, sorting

I've seen examples of the reverse question, but they don't help me with this direction.

I've got a List where T has an int weight. I'd like to divide this into lists of 5 grouped by weight.
if I have the following T's with respective weights
A:1
B:2
C:3
D:4
E:5
F:6
G:7
H:8
I:9
J:-11
I want {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}  to be sorted to {{J,A,B,C,D},{E,F,G,H,I}}
I'm not worried about cases where the number of items in the list isn't divisible by 5. And I'm not worried about the inners of the lists being sorted. For example I'd be happy with {{J,A,B,C,D},{F,I,G,H,E}} or even{{F,I,G,H,E},{J,A,B,C,D}}

Comment: What is the weight defined? How is it computed?

Comment: weight is public member of T, it's an int

Comment: In that case, what are the int values you are displaying between the braces?  Is that another property on T?  Why not show us what T looks like?  Will be very helpful and add clarity.

Comment: How exactly do you want it divided up?

Comment: clarified the question, I thought it was clear but it's always the case that the person talking thinks it's obvious for everyone else :P

Comment: If they are "grouped by weight", then there should be separate groups where each group contains the same value for "weight".  This does not jive with your sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = data.OrderBy(x => x.Weight)
                .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Group = i / 5 })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Group, x => x.Value, (k, g) => g.ToList())
                .ToList();
```

If you're happy with `query` being typed as simply `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` rather than `List<List<T>>` then you could leave out the `ToList` calls altogether:

```
var query = data.OrderBy(x => x.Weight)
                .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Group = i / 5 })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Group, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: I like the `i / 5` trick — but I would really strongly recommend to put a comment above this line of code that explains it, otherwise it is too unobvious to readers of the code.